# How do I set the node title?

Tags: nodes

I need to specify node titles when the node is created. I am hiding the title field from users and have everything working to generate the correct title but I can't seem to get that title into the node's title field. How do I get my title where it needs to go?

Comment: you can use Automatic Nodetitles: https://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle for this purpose

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using automatic node titles but couldn't get it to do what I needed. I have a create node form in a block on a 'parent' node. I need to use the parent node's title as the title of the new node. Using the replacement tokens in the automatic node title module resulted in the title of the block the form was in rather than the title of the parent node.

Comment: if so you have to use [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7). In that hook use your logic and set node title as $node->title ='your value'

Comment: Thanks! presave worked but I need to find a way to prevent it from updating every time the node is edited. Any suggestions?

Comment: I ended up checking if $node->nid was set to keep from running it more than once. The documentation was unclear on that but it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can insert that generated title with [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Auto Entity Label](https://drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) to set the title, it supports the use of tokens so you can add any field that is attached to the node to the title. You can also hide the title so the user cannot edit it if required.